# Go GC: are unsafe.Pointers followed recursively?

Tags: go, garbage-collection

I'm working with user-defined data structures, managing memory layout myself but leveraging the Go GC. I ran into a bug that I couldn't figure out for the last 2 days: some variables randomly change values.

When the GC is turned off, the issue disappears. It seems the memory is reused, hence the changing values.

What I know:

- the Go GC tracks unsafe.Pointers, so I always keep pointers stored as unsafe.Pointers.
- Go tracks metadata about values "on the side" to know which are ordinary values vs. unsafe.Pointers. [[source](https://go.dev/blog/ismmkeynote)]

But how does the GC know where a value ends?

See this example of a memory segment where each letter is a word (64bits):

```
[A, b, c, D, e, F]
```

Uppercase letters are unsafe.Pointers, lowercase are ordinary values.
I have an unsafe.Pointer to the above, so the GC knows to keep the values starting at `A`.
But does it need to follow unsafe.Pointers `D` & `F`?
It depends on where the value that starts at `A` ends.

How does it know?

Comment: "I'm working with user-defined data structures, managing memory layout myself" Good luck! (You'll need a lot of it). "`[A, b, c, D, e, F]` Uppercase letters are unsafe.Pointers, lowercase are ordinary values." This is basically impossible in Go unless the [ ... ] thing is of type `[]any` which probably it isn't. If it _is_ and A, D and F have been obtained via unsafe.Pointer then GC will "follow". "How does it know where the value that starts at A ends?" Slices (assuming the [...] thing is a slice) have defined memory layout, actually all elements have the same.

Comment: @Volker thx, clarified that `[A, b, c, D, e, F]` represents a memory segment. The Go GC is quite fascinating, it does actually follow unsafe.Pointers of unknown types, see source link in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Answering my own question. (You just need to work on articulating the question to soon find the answer..)

**Yes, unsafe.Pointers are followed.**

Values are stored in one of (currently 67) span classes each having a fixed size, hence the location of a value determines its length for GC purposes. (Any remaining bytes are probably zero-ed.)

[Source](https://www.sobyte.net/post/2021-12/golang-memory-allocator/)

To **debug**:

- set `clobberfree=1` on `GODEBUG` env var to overwrite freed memory segments with garbage data (eg. run `GODEBUG=clobberfree=1 go test`). This was the most useful debug tool for me, in conjunction with forcing GC via `runtime.GC()`. There are more handy options: [Environment variables](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#hdr-Environment_Variables).
- use [runtime.SetFinalizer()](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#SetFinalizer) to find unexpectedly freed objects